# How to hide headers for all the screens except for some selected screens in react native stack navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I need to keep the navigation header hidden for all the screens except for some screen for which I define whether to show the header or not. How can I do that in react native?

I tried several solutions from the internet but it didn't work. I am using Stack Navigration and Bottom Tab navigation in the project.

Answer (score 1):

There is a property called `screenOptions` for both the tab and stack navigators that has a `headerShown` option. You can use this property to disable the headers for any screens that belong to the navigator. Then, on the specific screens that you want to have headers, you can explicitly use the `options` property which also has a `headerShown` option. For example:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name='ScreenWithoutHeader' component={ExampleComponent} />
    <Stack.Screen
        name='ScreenWithHeader'
        component={ExampleComponent}
        options={{
            headerShown: true
        }}
    />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

You can use the same properties and options for `Tab.Navigator` and `Tab.Screen`. You can read more about these properties on the [React Native site](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headershown).